# Avahi / zeroconf address not working

Tags: networking, ssh, raspbian-buster

I am having difficulty in ssh-ing into Raspberry Pis via their mDNS (avhai / zeroconf) .local host names.

After reboot I can ssh into a pi as expected:

`$ ssh user@raspberrypi.local`

However after a period of time (it seems to be a day or two - but I've not measured it accurately) I can no-longer access the Pi's via their ".local" URI (ssh, ping, HTTP access, etc. all fail to connect); but I **can** still access the pi's via their IP addresses (e.g. `$ ssh user@192.168.1.100`). A reboot of the Pi restores the previous mDNS .local host name.

This effects multiple Pi's (both Pi 3 & 4); and it happens with both WiFi and ethernet connections.

I'm running Raspbian / Raspberry Pi OS on the Pi's; and networking via OpenWRT on Linksys hardware.

Any ideas?

Comment: Rather than reboot try `sudo systemctl restart avahi-daemon`.

Comment: That works perfectly @Dougie… Still not sure why avahi is falling over – but restarting it is a much preferable fix than a full reboot. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally caching prevents  Zero-conf resolution and the only cure I have found is to restart all network devices although pinging sometimes refreshes the arp cache.

You may be interested in the following script I use.
This falls back to a reserved IP Address if [Zero-conf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) fails.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to start ssh connection to Pi
# If not found use default ADDRESS
# 2019-07-30

TARGET="MilliwaysPi4.local"
ADDRESS="10.1.2.84"     # WiFi
ADDRESS2="10.1.2.74"    # Ethernet

ping -c1 $TARGET > /dev/null 2>&1
rc1=$?
if [ $rc1 -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Can't ping $TARGET"
    TARGET=$ADDRESS
    ping -c1 $TARGET > /dev/null 2>&1
    rc2=$?
    if [ $rc2 -gt 0 ]; then
        TARGET=$ADDRESS2
    fi
fi

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
    USR='pi'
else
    USR=$1
fi

ssh $USR@$TARGET
PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
```